# How to report bugs for Widlfly Communitiy Editions?

Tags: report, wildfly, issue-tracking

I'm using the CE of Widlfly, so I don't have any RedHat subscription.
Is there a way to report bugs to the CE?
Is there a way to get help from the experts on issues with the CE?

Thanks!
Greetings
Józsi

Answer (score 1):

Well all you need is on WildFly website: https://www.wildfly.org/contribute/

Comment: Especially [there](https://issues.redhat.com/projects/WFLY/issues/WFLY-15598?filter=allopenissues) you can create a ticket. You will need a Redhat account, but a free one (without costs for you) will be sufficient.